# Вывод значения из функции JS vanilla

Tags: javascript

Повесил обработчик события на колесо мыши, не могу вернуть переменную delta со значением в основной код.

```
var elemToScroll = document.getElementById('container');

if (elemToScroll.addEventListener) {
  if ('onwheel' in document) {
    // IE9+, FF17+
    elemToScroll.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
    // устаревший вариант события
    elemToScroll.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel);
  } else {
    // Firefox < 17
    elemToScroll.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel);
  }
} else { // IE8-
  elemToScroll.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel);
}

function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // deltaY, detail содержат пиксели
  // wheelDelta не дает возможность узнать количество пикселей
  // onwheel || MozMousePixelScroll || onmousewheel
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  var info = document.getElementById('delta');

  info.innerHTML = +info.innerHTML +  delta;

  console.log(delta);

  e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
}
```

Comment: А где вы ее возвращаете? Где `return`?

Comment: Где "основной код"? Подумайте - какой код вызывает вашу функцию `onWheel` , и интересует ли этот код, что там эта функция возвращает?

Comment: точно, спасибо! Сейчас проверю!

Comment: @DenisTsarkov очень интересно посмотреть. Рискну предположить, что не "не возвращает", а возвращает `undefined`, так?

Comment: В начале я возвращал число в блок HTML, но потом возникла необходимость вернуть его просто в переменную, уже замыленные мозги, прошу помочь, если не вижу кусок бревна в глазу.

Comment: "замыленные мозги" - возьму на вооружение. Уберите `var` перед `delta`.

Answer (score 2):

хмм... у меня все работает.

```js
var elemToScroll = document.getElementById('container');

if (elemToScroll.addEventListener) {
  if ('onwheel' in document) {
    // IE9+, FF17+
    elemToScroll.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
    // устаревший вариант события
    elemToScroll.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel);
  } else {
    // Firefox < 17
    elemToScroll.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel);
 }
} else { // IE8-
  elemToScroll.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel);
}



function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // deltaY, detail содержат пиксели
  // wheelDelta не дает возможность узнать количество пикселей
  // onwheel || MozMousePixelScroll || onmousewheel
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  var info = document.getElementById('delta');

  info.innerHTML = +info.innerHTML + delta;


  console.log(delta);




  e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
}
```

```css
#container{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<span>delta+= </span><h1 id="delta"> </h1>
<div id="container"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var delta = 0;
function onWheel(e) {
  // ...
  delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
  // ...
}
```